# How to display display another labels different from thoses of the variables used

Tags: r, label, bar-chart

Hello I would like to represent the barplot so that the diseases that are related to the same functional system are coloured in the same way. As it is easier to group similar diseases by their code, I have done so.  However, it's the disease labels that I want to display. But I can't group diseases that are similar by their labels because the labels have nothing in common (in my real dataframe) and I can't do it manually since I work on a large database. This is what my database might look like.

```
ID=1:20
Hospital<-sample(c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10)))
Disease<-c("D1000",rep("D2001",2),rep("D2000",3),rep("D3000",4),
           rep("D3001",2),rep("D3003",4),rep("D4001",3),"D4002")
labels<-c("Infection",rep("Cancer.type1",2),rep("Cancer.type0",3),
          rep("Trauma.type0",4),rep("Trauma.type1",2),
          rep("Trauma.type3",4),rep("Heart.type1",3),"Heary.type2"  )
data<-data.frame(ID,Hospital,Disease,labels)
data$Disease<-as.factor(data$Disease)
```

And below is how I plot the barchart. All the disease that start with D4 have the same colors.All those that start with D3 also have the colors. And so on. Now I want the disease labels to appear on the graphs rather than their codes.

```
data%>%count(Disease)%>%
ggplot(aes(x=Disease,y=n))+
geom_col(aes(fill=substr(Disease,1,2)),show.legend = F)+
coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add `labels` to your `count` function, and base the plot on that:

```r
data %>% 
  count(labels, Disease) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = labels, y = n)) +
    geom_col(aes(fill = substr(Disease,1,2)), show.legend = FALSE) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using `scale_x_discrete(labels= ...)` you can set the labels (since you used `coord_flip`, it is `x` instead of `y`). See for example the **Change tick marks** section [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-axis-ticks-a-guide-to-customize-tick-marks-and-labels#change-tick-mark-labels). You have to provide it a named vector, such as the one I generate in the first line below:

```
labels <- setNames(labels, Disease)

data%>%count(Disease)%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Disease,y=n))+
  geom_col(aes(fill=substr(Disease,1,2)),show.legend = F)+
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=labels)
```

Comment: Thank you Bas. You've already answered the second question I wanted to ask. That of changing the labels while maintaining the order of the code.